# mysql group number used more than once and add total cost

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help , I have date ,number ,duration and cost

i want to see a result where a number has been dialed more than once and total cost added together

```
date                     number     duration  cost
17/11/2014 10:32:19 am   0800       00:00:00  0.00
17/11/2014 11:06:47 am   071991     00:02:42  3.54
13/11/2014 02:47:40 pm   060302874  00:00:00  0.00
 6/11/2014 11:53:28 am   0100601555 00:00:47  0.50
24/11/2014 12:06:27 pm   0113151407 00:00:46  0.50
19/11/2014 08:37:34 am   0113941905 00:00:47  0.50
24/11/2014 02:48:43 pm   0113941905 00:00:29  0.50
19/11/2014 08:39:16 am   0113949182 00:01:03  0.50
24/11/2014 02:41:57 pm   0113949182 00:00:36  0.50
24/11/2014 12:08:09 pm   0113949182 00:00:43  0.50
24/11/2014 02:50:29 pm   0114922660 00:03:26  1.72
```

Comment: So date and duration are irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

A simple group by number should do it

```
select number, 
sum(cost) total_cost, 
count(*) times_dialed, 
min(date) earliest_date, 
max(date) latest_date
from mytable 
group by number
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Any particular reason for including earliest and latest date?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT number
     , SUM(cost) total 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY number 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+------------+-------+
| number     | total |
+------------+-------+
| 0113941905 |  1.00 |
| 0113949182 |  1.50 |
+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
number, sum(cost)
FROM myTable as a,
(SELECT 
    number, count(*) as dials
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1) as b
WHERE a.number = b.number 
and b.dials > 1
GROUP BY 1
```